# How can I type to "All chat" in Heroes of the Storm?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

How can I type to "All chat" in Heroes of the Storm?

And if you can't, are there ways to say GG/WP? I noticed someone on the enemy team did this the other day, but I don't know how.

Comment: The linked question is Mac OS specific, despite the answer being the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to communicate via text with the enemy team -- "All Chat" does not exist in Heroes of the Storm.

Similar to Hearthstone, however, there are a series of emotes your character can do, one of which is "Good Game". It's bound to <kbd>y</kbd> by default.

Simply hold down the button, then use the mouse to make a selection from the resultant flower of options.

Comment: I believe Heroes of the Storm emotes are still temporarily disabled since one of their more recent patches. The hotkey was 'Y' and in the past typing "gg" used to be sent to everyone, but was also removed temporarily.

Comment: I have confirmed typing gg is still possible.